# My Android Studio uses jre from file Android/Android Studio in JDK location.

Tags: android, android-studio

My Android Studio uses JRE from file Android/Android Studio in JDK location in the project structure settings. Is it okay or should I put my JDK location from C drive(where I actually installed JDK)? It works fine with the current path, though. Just wondering if I'm missing any additional features when I put my JDK location.